# Inexpensive way of fixing cracked area of concrete parking?

Tags: concrete

This is my parking. As you can see, there are sections of the concrete that have cracked. Also, there's soil under the concrete. The parking's pretty narrow, so I don't have too much space between the car door and the concrete wall.

I don't mind leaving it as-is, but I don't want to step in a puddle when it rains. People that I've called to fix it want to replace the whole thing, which is very expensive.

So my question, is there an inexpensive way to fix the are of the concrete in the picture? It doesn't have to be pretty, it just has to be functional.

As you can see, the puddle starts where the tires rest after parking the car. But if it rains too much, the puddle will be much bigger and it becomes impossible to get out of my car without stepping into a puddle.

[image]

Comment: Does that concrete slab continue under the adjacent building?  If it's cracking there and water is getting in, that could be a much bigger problem than stepping in a puddle.

Comment: Leave it as is and put crushed stone in the low spots.

Comment: I would just add a few bags of gravel into the low lying areas. That keeps the whole area non-puddle-ing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fix that concrete. It's badly disintegrating and any patch will quickly degrade as well.

You can pour new concrete, or you can replace with something like driveway pavers, which would help alleviate the water issue since they're porous. You'd want to provide a good, well-draining substrate.

The project could be inexpensive if you can source some second-hand or otherwise unwanted pavers. I purchased almost 1000 driveway-grade paver bricks for $40 a few years back. The owner just wanted them off his property.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do what Romans did.

[image: roman road]

Go to a nearby river and collect some stones/boulders and gravel and build a stone road.

It's cheap and should last for a millennia without visible cracks. 
No cement needed. 
You may also choose pre-made bricks, but that's gonna be slightly more expensive.

Comment: Yeah, don't be yanking stones out of public property. Get them from a less destructive source, like a farmer's pick pile.

Comment: And you need more than just the surface stones, the Romans had road building well understood.